# db:migrate creates the file db/development.sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rake, postgis

db:migrate creates the file db/development.sqlite3 if the rails app uses sqlite. I prefer to use postgresql for development and production before deploying to heroku.

Part of my database.yml file:

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
host: localhost
database: app-development
username: postgres
password: *******
```

When I run bundle exec rake db:migrate should I be expecting a file such as db/development.postgresql? Because no file is created in the db directory and neither is an error produced.

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "users_id_seq" for serial column "
users.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "users_pkey" for table
"users"
-> 0.2060s
==  CreateUsers: migrated (0.2070s) ===========================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `postgresql` is very very different from `sqlite`. Try reading this article so you can spot the main differences:

http://saaientist.blogspot.com.br/2007/07/choice-of-databases-or-postgres-vs.html.

The thing about your question is that sqlite work with a database file inside your application folder, and postgres don't work this way. There are plenty of resources on how postgresql work with Rails, and i recommend you to read some and try to understand.